# How to detect browser height, subtract a certain number of pixels, then output the number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible? Use of jQuery is also available.

Comment: Browser height or window height or document height?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the Browser height, is there?

Comment: @AbidSonny Can you tell us **why** do you need height of **browser** window? Maybe there's another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said "browser height" both in the question and, when asked to clarify, in the comments on the question.

The answer is: **No**, it isn't possible to find out the height of the **browser** window. But then, 99.99999% of the time, you don't care.

You can find out:

- The height of the displayed area of the page (the viewport) via `$(window).height()`; [more](http://api.jquery.com/height)
- The height of the document as a whole (which can be shorter or taller than the viewport) via `$(document).height()` (same link)
- And usually even the height of the user's screen (via [`window.screen.height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen))

None of these gives you the height of the *browser window*, though.

Answer (score 1):

You either need:

```
$(window).height();//viewport
```

OR

```
$(document).height();//complete document
```

OR

```
window.screen.height;//screen resolution height
```

It returns an **integer** value, so you can do calculations on it

Answer (score 1):

The following code sets the variables winW and winH to the inner width and height of the browser window, and outputs the width and height values. If the user has a very old browser, then winW and winH are set to 630 and 460, respectively.

```
var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}

document.writeln('Window width = '+winW);
document.writeln('Window height = '+winH);
```

[taken from here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm)
You can ofcourse substract/add/multiply/whatever you want before printing the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( $(window).height() - 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`height()` is what you are looking for..

http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
var heght= $(window).height(); //this gives you the height of the window
alert(heght - 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDocHeight() {
var D = document;
return Math.max(
    Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
) - mynumber ;
}
```

If the actual document’s body height is less than the viewport height then it will return the viewport height instead.

And jQuery Method:

```
$.getDocHeight = function(){
 var D = document;
 return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight,    D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
};

alert( $.getDocHeight() - mynumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
   document.body.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for height function of Jquery like this
     `$(window).height()  or $(document).height()`

and for subtracting pixels just use     `$(window).height()-5`